# Plot a histogram of the top 3 most eaten fruit by gender using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(Gender=c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F"), Strawberry=c(1,2,2,1,5), Pineapple=c(1,5,4,1,3), Apple=c(1,1,1,1,1), Grapefruit=c(9,2,4,1,2))
```

and I would like to show in a histogram the top 3 most eaten fruit by gender and the amount they have eaten using ggplot. The main problem is how to do this in one plot (i.e. I would like to do this in a facet_grid).

I can compute them each individually and make a plot out of that by creating a temporary dataset:

```
tmp.data <- colSums(dt[Gender == "M"][, .(Strawberry, Pineapple, Apple, Grapefruit)])
```

But not really sure how to combine them into one plot.

**Update**

What I am trying to achieve is to have a grid, with in this case because we have two genders, two graphs. Next to each other, where each of those graphs are histograms with the top 3 most eaten fruit by gender (e.g. so only three bars in the histograms).

So the result should be something like:

Plot 1 - M
y-axis: frequency
x-axis fruits that are most eaten by male (in this case: Grapefruit, Pineapple and Strawberry)

So we have three bars in plot 1, the first being of Pineapple, which are eaten 14 times, second is Pineapple bar, which has a height of 6, Strawberry has a height of 4.

Now the second plot will be:

Plot 2 - F
x-axis different fruits, because females in my sample eat primarily Pineapple, Strawberry and Grapefruit.

So we have 3 bars again, the first one is of Pineapple, second strawberry and last one of Grapefruit.

I hope this is a bit better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, using `reshape2` and `dplyr` to fix the data:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
dt$id <- row.names(dt)
dt <- melt(dt, id = row.names(id))
dt <- dt %>% group_by(Gender, variable) %>% 
             summarise(total = sum(value)) %>%
             group_by(Gender) %>%
             filter(total %in% sort(total, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])

ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = variable, y=total)) +
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + facet_grid(~Gender)
```

I'm sure the rearrangement could be done in fewer steps...